# Implementing Custom Functionality in Existing PyTorch Layers

Tags: python, class, methods, deep-learning, pytorch

In Pytorch,
I want to add a function that performs a specific function for all **layers** that inherit from `nn.Module`.

Here, the **layer** means:
`nn.Linear` / `nn.Conv2d` / `nn.MaxPool2d` / etc.

First, create a new main class and layer class that inherits from `nn.Module`.

```py
class Main(nn.Module):
    def foo(self, x):
        x += 2
        return x 

class Linear(nn.Module, Main):
    pass

class Conv2d(nn.Module, Main):
    pass

...
```

Using multiple inheritance as above, you can use the method **'foo'** with the existing layer functionality.

Let's call the existing layer such as `nn.Linear` as **A**, and the newly created layer class as **B**.

When composing a new model, there is no problem when using **B**.
ex)

```py
class NewModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = Linear(64, 64)  # this Linear object is B, 'foo' method available
```

However, models using **A** (internal classes Cifar10, ResNet50, etc. in torchvision)
cannot use the **'foo'** method.

I also thought about putting the **'foo'** method into the objects using **A** with features like `setattr`,

There is the inconvenience of having to open all Modules of the **A** object and check them, and it is also difficult to track internal calculations.

Without modifying the library, is there an appropriate way to solve the above problem?

Comment: Maybe you should look into [`nn.Module.apply`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=nn+module+apply#torch.nn.Module.apply). Overriding `nn.Module` directly doesn't seem reasonable nor feasible.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your function will do? Potentially you could use hooks for that

Comment: @YakovDan Thank you for the answer.
I need this feature for calculating LRP, one of the eXplainable AI (XAI) algorithms. If the relevance calculation formula is predefined for each layer, only the method with the same name needs to be called during the calculation.